# How to read all .csv files from a folder in python or Matlab and write the output?

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, numpy

My folder contains 'n' number of .csv files. Each file contains seven columns. I want to find the difference between a maximum and a minimum point for a 5th column.

How to find this difference for all the .csv files one after other and write the result in a separate file?

Comment: Are all the datatypes the same in the columns which require these comparisons? Please post sample data, code attempt and expected output.

Comment: Do you want to us to make a module exclusively to you? What did you try so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: All data types are the same in the column. I am a science background student and new to python and Matlab. If you provide steps of instructions and snippet of the code that will be a great help for me.

Comment: Please, provide more information about what are you trying to do. Are you trying to find the difference between max and min for 5th column in each table? Or between one table and others? In any case you need at first import files. Use pandas.

Comment: For each file, I want to find the difference between a maximum and a minimum point in the 5th column. Like that, I want to do it for all the files in a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, you could do this:

```
% List all CSV files
fnames = dir('*.csv');
% Pre-allocate output vector
ranges = zeros(numel(fnames), 1);
% Loop over file names
for idx = 1:numel(fnames)
    % Read the CSV data
    data = readmatrix(fnames(idx).name);
    % Get the 5th column
    col5 = data(:,5);
    % Get the range for this file
    ranges(idx) = max(col5) - min(col5);
end
% Write the result
writematrix(ranges, 'ranges.csv');
```

[`readmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html) and [`writematrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) are both *relatively* recent - R2019a.

Comment: Dear Edric, Thank you so much for understanding my situation. I am a research scholar, and I am from a science background. As a learner, I am struggling in the post-processing of the simulation data. I am using Matlab R2020b. I got this error for the code you've shared. Brace indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Error in Readfiles (line 8)
    data = readmatrix(fnames{idx});  Could you please help me out

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't actually test the code. Edited the answer.

Comment: Dear Edric, The programme is not reading the files in proper order. The order of the files is sky_0, sky_1, sky_2,... sky_2001.
But it is reading in the order sky_0, sky_1, sky_10, sky_1000, sky_1001,... sky_1009, sky_10,... Could you please help me out, sir?

Comment: Dear Edric, I resolved the problem. Thank you so much again for your code.